# Create custom action in ResourceController in Sylius

Tags: php, symfony, sylius

I have a custom controller extending `ResourceController` and I am trying to create a custom action `public function redeemAction(Request $request): Response`

```
namespace App\Controller;

use Sylius\Bundle\ResourceBundle\Controller\ResourceController;

class OrderPointsController extends ResourceController
{
    public function redeemAction(Request $request): Response {

    }
}
```

Here is my route in sylius_shop.yaml

```
app_shop_account_redeem_points:
    path: /account/points/redeem
    methods: [POST]
    defaults:
        _controller: app.controller.order_points:redeemAction
```

And the resource.yaml:

```
sylius_resource:
    resources:
        app.order_points:
            classes:
                model: App\Entity\Order\OrderPoints
                repository: App\Repository\OrderPointsRepository
```

When I access the route by POST, I get this error:

> The controller for URI "/account/points/redeem" is not callable:
> Expected method "redeemAction" on class
> "Sylius\Bundle\ResourceBundle\Controller\ResourceController", did you
> mean "createAction", "deleteAction", "indexAction"?

I understand that the resource controllers are supposed to perform CRUD actions, but some core Sylius files also call custom actions:

```
sylius_shop_cart_summary:
    path: /
    methods: [GET]
    defaults:
        _controller: sylius.controller.order:summaryAction
        _sylius:
            template: "@SyliusShop/Cart/summary.html.twig"
            form: Sylius\Bundle\OrderBundle\Form\Type\CartType
```

.

```
namespace Sylius\Bundle\OrderBundle\Controller;

class OrderController extends ResourceController
{
    public function summaryAction(Request $request): Response
    {
        $configuration = $this->requestConfigurationFactory->create($this->metadata, $request);

        $cart = $this->getCurrentCart();
        if (null !== $cart->getId()) {
            $cart = $this->getOrderRepository()->findCartById($cart->getId());
        }

        if (!$configuration->isHtmlRequest()) {
            return $this->viewHandler->handle($configuration, View::create($cart));
        }

        $form = $this->resourceFormFactory->create($configuration, $cart);

        $view = View::create()
            ->setTemplate($configuration->getTemplate('summary.html'))
            ->setData([
                'cart' => $cart,
                'form' => $form->createView(),
            ])
        ;

        return $this->viewHandler->handle($configuration, $view);
    }

    ...        

}
```

Is there a way to call another action than the predefined CRUD actions in a custom controller extending resource controller ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing the Controller in resource.yaml:

```
sylius_resource:
    resources:
        app.order_points:
            classes:
                model: App\Entity\Order\OrderPoints
                repository: App\Repository\OrderPointsRepository
                controller: App\Controller\OrderPointsController
```